# How to Loop through the List in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a list which is filled with a data fetched from DB.

My Code:

```
 Dim lst As New List(Of MyClass)
 lst = GetData()
```

MyClass looks like the following:

```
Public Class MyClass
   Public Overridable Property Id as Integer
   Public Overridable Property Questions as String
   Public Overridable Property Comments as String
End Class
```

I am trying to loop the `lst`

```
 For Each item As String In lst
   'Some data manipulation
 Next
```

But I am unable to loop it through using the above code.It throws following error:

Value of Type 'MyClass' cannot be converted to 'String'

Whats arong here? Any Help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: lst is a List with objects of type MyClass, and you are trying to iterate them as Strings

Comment: It's a list of `MyClass` not `String`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
 For Each item As MyClass In lst
   'Some data manipulation
 Next
```