# What is the easiest way to get a value in JSON array based on another value?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

Here is my JSON:

```json
{
"contacts": [{
    "identity-profiles": [{
        "identities": [{
            "type": "EMAIL",
            "value": "twitterman@twitter.com",
            "timestamp": 1531322937327,
            "is-primary": true
        }, {
            "type": "LEAD_GUID",
            "value": "10000-10000-10000-10000",
            "timestamp": 1531322937344
        }]
    }],
},
}
```

I would like to get the value WHERE the type = "Email". My problem is, it may appear as below so it's not always the same order as above:

```json
{
"contacts": [{
    "identity-profiles": [{
        "identities": [{
            "type": "LEAD_GUID",
            "value": "10000-10000-10000-10000",
            "timestamp": 1531322937344              
        }, {
            "type": "EMAIL",
            "value": "twitterman@twitter.com",
            "timestamp": 1531322937327,
            "is-primary": true
        }]
    }],
},
}
```

This is currently my VB code which only gives me the value that comes first in the JSON array:

```
For Each item In jcontacts.ToList()
    Dim portalId = item("portal-id").ToString()
    Dim associatedCompanyId = If(item("properties")("associatedcompanyid")?("value").ToString, DBNull.Value)
    Dim contactId = item("vid").ToString()
    Dim firstName = If(item("properties")("firstname")?("value").ToString(), DBNull.Value)
    Dim lastName = If(item("properties")("lastname")?("value").ToString(), DBNull.Value)
    Dim email = If(item("identity-profiles")(0)("identities")?("value").ToString(), DBNull.Value)
    Dim telephone = If(item("properties")("phone")?("value").ToString(), DBNull.Value)
    Dim createDate = If(item("addedAt").ToString(), DBNull.Value)
    Dim modifiedDate = If(item("properties")("lastmodifieddate")?("value").ToString(), DBNull.Value)
Next
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In that case you'd need to loop through the "identity-profiles" list until you come to the entry you need.

Comment: Coming from a SQL background, I'd like to avoid using a loop within a loop if possible, will use that if nobody else has any ideas. @ADyson

Comment: well VB is not set-based, looping is the way to iterate through a list. Even if you can use something like linq to do it in a single statement, under the hood it probably just uses a loop anyway.

Comment: @ADyson is there any chance you could provide an example of how to do this? I'm not so familiar with VB so would be really handy. Had a look around Google and couldn't see anything initially.

Comment: You can surely google how to iterate through a list using VB.NET? Here's one of the first results from google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50241222/how-to-loop-through-the-list-in-vb-net . Or maybe the "identity-profiles" object is an array, or a collection, or something else? I don't know because I can't see your data.

Comment: @ADyson yes I am doing that currently as per my above code, however, I need to be able to say, where the key Type = 'Email', give me the value (which in this case is "twitterman@twitter.com"). I am not sure how to do that. Doing another loop brings me to the same problem whereby I can't return the value I need.

Comment: what you're looping through now is the "jcontacts" list. Now you need an inner loop to loop through the "identity-profiles" list / array / collection / whatever-it-is, and when you reach an entry where the type is "email", collect the content of the value field and exit the loop. `var profiles = item("identity-profiles")  For Each profile In profiles`...etc would start you off I think

Comment: @ADyson I just am not sure how you do that :( sorry, ill try and do some more research to figure out how. Thanks for your help. Edit: ah just seen your above example - that helps, will see if I can go from there!

Comment: No problem. It's just another loop similar to the one you're already using.

Comment: @ADyson have provided an answer below now which seems to be working for me, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ADyson for pointing me in the right direction. This is my loop now:

```
For Each item In jcontacts.ToList()
    Dim portalId = item("portal-id").ToString()
    Dim associatedCompanyId = If(item("properties")("associatedcompanyid")?("value").ToString, DBNull.Value)
    Dim contactId = item("vid").ToString()
    Dim firstName = If(item("properties")("firstname")?("value").ToString(), DBNull.Value)
    Dim lastName = If(item("properties")("lastname")?("value").ToString(), DBNull.Value)
    Dim email = Nothing
    Dim profile = item("identity-profiles")(0)("identities")
    For Each sitem In profile
        If (sitem("type").ToString() = "EMAIL") Then
            email = sitem("value").ToString()
            Exit For
        Else
            email = DBNull.Value
        End If
        Next
    Dim telephone = If(item("properties")("phone")?("value").ToString(), DBNull.Value)
    Dim createDate = If(item("addedAt").ToString(), DBNull.Value)
    Dim modifiedDate = If(item("properties")("lastmodifieddate")?("value").ToString(), DBNull.Value)
Next
```